# Error when opening preview in Craft CMS 3

Tags: php, environment-variables, craftcms

I'm very new to Craft.

In my tutorial of craftquest i am trying to open the preview of an entry but im receiving an error.

```
HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: website.ruud.local/website.ruud.local/section/entry
```

When remove the value `website.ruud.local` in my .env for `PRIMARY_SITE_URL` the error is fixed.

This doesn't look right. any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

In the error it shown that the “website.ruud.local” is doubled in your PRIMARY_SITE_URL in env file. So system can’t able to find the assigned template for the page to preview it. You can add the PRIMARY_SITE_URL like shown in the image below.

[image]

Also do not forgot to assign the template at the bottom of your section's form like shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Make sure the URI is correct. URI should be the part which you want in url after your PRIMARY_SITE_URL.

Example: http://localhost/craft-project/web/about-us using this url you can able to access your about.twig template for preview.